# Filter, sort, limit, skip subdocument mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

```
const A = mongoose.Schema({
...
    bs: [B.schema],
...

 });
```

So basically i have two schemas, and one is subdocument of another.
From my datatable i get params. like filter, page limit, page, sort...

What i need to do is, to create query that will with _id from A schema get all his B schemas and always sort, limit, skip, filter with params. that i sent

I tried something like this

```
b = await A.find({'_id' : idA}, 
    { 'bs' : 
        { $slice: [ offset * limit, limit ]
        }
    });
```

And it's working but i can't still figure out how to filter and sort.
So if somebody have some idea welcome to share.

P.S Sorry for bad english
Regards,
Salesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not `find` A documents that fulfill your array criteria, but to modify the results to accommodate to your needs. You can do this with two approaches, depending on where you want the processing to be done:

#### 1. [Use MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation-array/). The processing is done in the DB.

The aggregation pipeline is a series of steps you determine that documents go through being queried and transformed.
  A rough untested (and probably syntactically wrong) example would be:

```
A.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "id" }},
  { $project: {
      bs: {
        $filter: { input: "$bs" , as: "filteredBs" , cond: { /* conditions object */}  }},
     } 
  },    
  { $slice: ["$filteredBs", offset * limit, limit ] }
  /* ... */
]);
```

#### 2. Get the document by Id and process the array on your server.

Here you're just limited by javascript and its array capabilites.

```
const found = A.findById('id');
const bs = A.bs.filter( /* filter function */ ).slice() // ... whatever you want.
A.bs = bs;
return A;
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. So basically, look it like this. I have schema Contract, and i want to present in my datatable all Documents that my schema Contract have (arrays of objects), so basically i don't need schema Contract, i just need to find Contract by id, get his "documents" and sort/filter/limit/skip them...

Comment: Both options I listed can do just that. Just replace the names and tweak the syntax based on MongDB docs examples.

Comment: Getting "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$filter' => should i have $project or something like that ?

Comment: You're right, the $filter aggregation is done inside a $project. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Comment: Ok, i did that, but still for example i get from my fronted { "name" : "-1"} where should I put $sort when I can't put him in filter, same where should i put for example my search filter { "name" : "/d"}  (its regexp generate this /d)